# Links for table not working

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I have come here, because I can't get the table links (the images in black with text) to lead me anywhere. I have search for a solution but I didn't find it so please help....

I'm so desperate to get a quick response that I'm posting the hole page, Updated the image links also... so here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/1q2gj2rL/

I really need a way to make it work to keep using the tables, and I got out of ideas on how to fix this.

Specific code:

```
<table width="664" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="galeria_foto">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th width="146" scope="col"><img src="images/FLOWERS color.jpg" width="151" height="40" border="0"></th>

    <th width="22" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="147" scope="col"><a href="landscapes.html"><img src="images/LANDSCAPESnegro.jpg"
```

etc.... It's a mess, code not mine.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what isn't working? I'm on the site, and all of the white-on-black header links are working for me.

Comment: Your `img` tags are not closed correctly. They should look like `<img src="..." />`

Comment: the img is not what I'm searching for. is for the other page, I can't find an error for the links (landscapes, portraits) because there aren't working.... But in the old page is working :/ here is the old page: http://claudiacabrera.cl/flowers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for all of you that are having the same problem.

if you search trought my web code you will find that the body div has the property of `z-index:-1`, well that was the actual problem. Removing it will make all your links, overscroll, js actions, etc. work! is that simple. (It took me a day to realise this, please give a vote :3)

a small link of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/ft94qhea/

Comment: resize to see the menu list... Else look at the working scroll

Answer (score 0):

On your site you made a  tag with nothing in it , try to put the  tag around your table content.
else you have nothing to click on.

for exemple:

```
<a href:"URL.jpg" > <td>I am a Flower</td>  </a>
```